# Redmine allow user to view only one issue

Tags: permissions, bug-tracking, redmine, user-permissions

I have a Redmine installation and would like the ability to grant a user the ability to view (and maybe update) a single issue (not all issues in the project). The catch is that the issue is reported by someone else.

Use Case:
Users A,B, and admin C

1. admin C creates two bug reports 1 and 2
2. admin C wants to grant view access to user A on bug 1
3. admin C wants to grant view access to user B on bug 2
4. User A should not be able to access bug2
5. User B should not be able to access bug1

Can this be done with Redmine?  I have been messing around with the settings, but I don't see an easy way to accomplish this use case.

If not, are there other bug trackers that do allow for such a use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign view permissions on single issues in redmine.

From the top of my head, you may use one of the following approaches in your scenario:

- If you have only a limited number of users, you may be able to add **different trackers** (*ACIssues* and BCIssues), create two roles (*AC* and *BC*), associate user A and C with role *AC*, user B and C with role *BC*, and set permissions so that role *AC* has access to *ACIssues*, and role *BC* has access to *BCIssues*.
- [**Private issues**](http://www.redmine.org/issues/7414) work the way you describe if issue 1 is assigned to user A, and issue 2 is assigned to user B.

Comment: Your second solutions sounds like it might work for me.  I will try it out and accept the answer if it does.

Answer (score 5):

You have at least a couple of more options.

1. Create a new role 'View Own Issues'. Give it issue visibility to just created or assigned issues, flag "Issues can be assigned to this role" and enable just "View issues" and "Add notes".

   Then, you can assign each issue to the proper user.

   The advantage with a private issue is that you can have a set of privileged users as Reporters that will still be able to inspect the issue, since it is still public.

   The downside is that just one user can be assigned to the issue, therefore you have limited freedom.
2. Create a subproject that represents a visibility context and add members as needed. Move the issue to the subproject. You can still see the issue at the upper level, where assigned visibility is shown by the 'Project' field.